# What is the difference between Après d'être and Après être, or similarly, Après d'avoir and Après d'avoir , in the past infinitive

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, infinitif

For example:

***Après avoir vécu** en Australie pendant 10 ans, il a commencé à oublier sa langue natale.*

Compared to,

***Avant d'avoir donné** naissance à mes trois enfants*

Similarly,

*Il se sentait plus en forme **après être allé** à la salle de sport.*

Compared to,

***Avant d'être partie** à l'étranger,elle avait, peur de l'inconnu!*

Why, in the second versions of the past infinitive is there a 'de'?

Recently, I also found a phrase:

*Il ne faut pas vendre la peau de l'ours **avant de l'avoir tué**.*

Why in the case immediately above is there a de l'?

Is there any other cases that I should be made aware of?

Comment: How about that _d'_ is there in many instances just to avoid the collision of the sounds in _avant_ and _avoir_? _Avant avoir_ is just difficult to say.

Answer (score 1):

In modern French, the construction is always *avant de* + infinitif et *après* + infinitif.

Comment: And the *le* after *avant de* in “Il ne faut pas vendre la peau de l'ours avant de l'avoir tué” is a pronoun with antecedent *l’ours*: “before killing **it**.

Comment: Indeed, that's the kind of asymmetry you also find in "après que + indicatif" and "avant que + subjonctif" (for instance "après que je suis allé" and "avant que je sois allé").